# Cipher.doFinal() returning part of decrypted string for a long string

Tags: java, encryption, aes, aes-gcm, block-cipher

I am experiencing an issue when decrypting a string using sunjce :

```
javax.crypto.Cipher cipher =
      javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
  GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(Constants.GCM_TAG_BYTES * 8, nonce);
  cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, dataKey, spec);

  cipher.update(ciphertext);
  
  return cipher.doFinal();
```

if I pass the whole ciphertext to doFinal it works correctly but if I call it correctly it only returns partial string. FOr instance for the input

```
String jsonExample = "{\"dataType\":\"STRING\",\"strValue\":\"000000\"}";
```

The decrypted bytes only contain "000000" but if I use

```
return cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
```

and remove the update so it correctly prints the original string. What might be the reason? if I pass an empty byte array to doFinal after the update it also results in the same data loss. I want to know the logic behind it, it passes for small texts but for texts of this size it simply does not work.

this is my input

```
String jsonExample = "{\"dataType\":\"STRING\",\"strValue\":\"000000\"}";
```

This is how I am printing the decrypted string

```
String decryptedString = new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This is how I am passing the input string as bytes to the encrypt function

```
text = jsonExample.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

this is how I am calling encrypt

```
GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(Constants.GCM_TAG_BYTES * 8, nonce);
try {
  cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, dek, spec);
  byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(text);
```

When I use `cipher.update(ciphertext)` during decryption followed by `cipher.doFinal()` or `cipher.doFInal(new byte[0])` it only returns

`"000000"` after  I use the returned `byte[]` to `String decryptedString = new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

But if I directly call `cipher.doFInal(cipherText)` during decryption the result string I get is the original string.

Comment: What is your actual problem? What is the output you wanted vs. what you actually got. How are you 'printing' these outputs? Make a self-contained example. The accompanying text is not at all clear. A self-contained example bridges over almost all problems with explaining it.

Comment: It's clearer now, but the effect you observe is not possible. Most likely something unrelated to what you describe is going on. A self-contained example would be a good idea here.

Comment: And for some reason, it only happens in our production, same code. Do you suspect any environmental variables?

Comment: it works for me. But you have little tiny confusing snippets. A complete [mre] would not take much more space.

Answer (score 0):

**You're not using SunJCE, you're using the BouncyCastle provider.** (You *are* using the Sun/Oracle *API* -- JCA, Java Crypto Architecture -- if that's what you meant to say, but not the *provider* SunJCE.)

**Most** Ciphers in JCA return partial data from each or any `update` call (in either encrypt or decrypt direction), thus in general if you use `update` you must concatenate that value (or those values if multiple calls) plus any value returned from `doFinal` *before* using the result for anything that needs it to be complete, such as decoding UTF8. (Typically the easiest way is to `.write` them all to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, or `.put` them all to a `ByteBuffer`, but there are other options.) However the SunJCE provider does NOT do this for GCM, in the decryption direction only, apparently because the spec (SP800-38D) calls for the plaintext not to be released if the authentication fails, which can only be determined at `.doFinal` time, and then it returns *all* the plaintext.

The Bouncy provider does 'stream' GCM decryption, arguably in violation of the spec but consistent with usual and traditional JCA behavior, so most of the data is returned from the `update` call with only the last few bytes from `doFinal` and you need to concatenate these as above -- or, as you've found, just don't use `update` at all: if the data all fit in one buffer when encrypting, it should also fit when decrypting.

The Bouncy provider must buffer an amount of data equal to the tag so that it can remove and verify said tag; the "small texts" where your code works -- because decrypt `.update` returns nothing -- will be ones up to but not exceeding your tag size, which is apparently 8 bytes.

Comment: I used sun jce too same output.

Comment: Actually i used sun jce before and update returned an empty array. And my ciphertext already contains the tag. I am sending an empty byte array to diFinal. But this makes the doFinal return value truncated. Is this a bug?

Comment: Your comments conflict. SunJCE returns _empty_ on update and _everything_ on doFinal; this is NOT the same as Bouncy which returns most of the data on update and only the last part on doFinal. I explained both of these. Calling doFinal with an empty byte-array is exactly the same as calling with no argument at all; I didn't distinguish these because they don't need to be distinguished. What does need to be distinguished is the provider.